# grails domain mappedBy "none" not working on unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-orm

Currently using Grails 2.4.4

I'm trying to save my models without them assuming bidirectional relationship. So I added `mappedBy [field:'none']`. But it is not working on unit test. It works when I run the app, but when I run unit test and save the domains, they always assume bidirectional relationship.

Consider example (I omitted the constraints for simplicity, consider the fields nullable):

```
class User {
    Organization organization
    static mappedBy = [organization: 'none']
}

class Organization {
    User leader
    static mappedBy = [leader: 'none']
}
```

Whenever I do a:

```
def user = new User().save()
def organization = new Organization(leader: user).save()
user.organization = organization
user.save()

def organization2 = new Organization(leader: user).save()
// now user's organization becomes organization2
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use unit tests for persistence testing.

The implementation of GORM used in unit tests doesn't use a database, only a `ConcurrentHashMap`. Most of the core GORM features are supported, but as you are seeing there are gaps.

To properly test persistence, use integration tests, which by default use an in-memory H2 database but it's simple to change that in DataSource.groovy to a test MySQL/Postgres/etc. database if you prefer.